# (XNA) Make a new Texture2D out of another Texture2D

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, monogame, texture2d

I want to separate an image into multiple texture2ds using a for loop.

[image: https://puu.sh/wu16F/44bef38289.png]

I want to do something like this:

```
newTexture = Texture2D.CopyImage(biggerTexture, x, y, width, height);
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using `GetData` and `SetData`?

I just wrote an extension method for testing purposes:

```
public static class TextureExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new texture from an area of the texture.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="graphics">The current GraphicsDevice</param>
    /// <param name="rect">The dimension you want to have</param>
    /// <returns>The partial Texture.</returns>
    public static Texture2D CreateTexture(this Texture2D src, GraphicsDevice graphics, Rectangle rect)
    {
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(graphics, rect.Width, rect.Height);
        int count = rect.Width * rect.Height;
        Color[] data = new Color[count];
        src.GetData(0, rect, data, 0, count);
        tex.SetData(data);
        return tex;
    }
}
```

You can now call it like so:

```
newTexture = sourceTexture.CreateTexture(GraphicsDevice, new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100));
```

If you just want to draw a part of the texture, you could use the `SpriteBatch` overload like domi1819 suggested.

Comment: I used the sourceRectangle solution in my game, so right now, I'm currently drawing the entire tileset for my game on each tile, but cropping it with sourceRectangle. Thanks for this solution though, If I need it, I might use it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind is using `Texture2D.FromStream()` but that reads a whole image file so it won't really work in your case.

What I did for one of my games is create a wrapper around `Texture2D` that only draws specific parts of the texture using a `SpriteBatch.Draw()` overload that accepts source and destination rectangles.

Comment: I used the sourceRectangle solution in my game, so right now, I'm currently drawing the entire tileset for my game on each tile, but cropping it with sourceRectangle.

Comment: @emil1000123 Just FYI, you don't actually draw the whole texture when you use source rectangle to crop it, your GPU is plenty capable of efficiently cropping at runtime.